# Create custom angular captcha

Tags: angular, api, asp.net-core, captcha

I want to use custom captcha for my angular project.
I don't want to use google recaptcha.
I used .net core for backend.
I want a captcha contains letters and digits.

One approach that I am thinking about is to create a get api to get generated base64 image and an encrypted code from backend.
show the image to users.
Get user's input value and post to backend (post encrypted code and user's value) and receive true/false result from backend.

1. Is it right/safe to send encrypted code to client?
2. Is this method secure enough?
3. Is there any better idea about doing that?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

> Is it right/safe to send encrypted code to client ?

Generally, the verification code is stored in the session, so it should be sufficiently secure.

I found an excellent source code, which contains many sample codes for angular, webapi, webapp, etc. You can refer to it.

[DNTCaptcha.Core Public](https://github.com/VahidN/DNTCaptcha.Core/tree/master/src)